# SQL Query - If discriminator in table equals something, change column content in another table to equal PK

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

Say I have two tables(TableA and TableB)

TableA has an Id (primary key) and a discriminator with a certain value (eg. "stuff")
TableB has an id column which is essentially a foreign key of TableA id ("StuffId")

What I would like to do is to make an SQL query for TableB which checks the discriminator value for "stuff" (for example) in TableA and if the value is "stuff", take the Id (primary key) of tableA and link that value for TableB in the column "StuffId"

Is this doable?

Thank you

yes there already existing rows.

**TableA might have**

```
ID     Discriminator
--------------------    
1         stuff
2        notstuff
3         stuff
```

**TableB might have**

```
StuffID     Name
-----------------    
   43       ffr
   87       fd
```

I would like the stuffId column to be the same as the column in TableA but only if the discriminator in TableA is "stuff"

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to do, could you provide an example? Are there existing rows in TableB that you want to update or do you just want to insert new rows with the StuffId set to the Id from TableA where the discriminator is 'Stuff'?

Comment: Reading this is some what confusing? Provide table examples with some sample data.

Comment: If it's the latter the following query should do the trick: INSERT TableB (StuffId) SELECT Id from TableA WHERE discriminator='Stuff'

Comment: yes there already existing rows. 
TableA might have

ID     Discriminator
1         stuff
2        not stuff
3         stuff

TableB might have
StuffID     Name
   43       ffr
   87        fd

I would like the stuffId column to be the same as the column in TableA but only if the discriminator in TableA is "stuff"

Comment: @jpw edited by original post

Comment: @jpw Ill give that a try, hang on

Comment: @jpw Right I think that works, however, what if I had 2 columns in TableB. For the other, its the same idea but looks for "notstuff" (for example) in TableA. What then? Thank you btw (also, you should put your answer up properly and ill rank you up :)

Comment: @user1290653 I'll repost my suggestion. As for the second scenario I'm a bit confused about the question. Do you mean to check both for the discriminator as well as something else or just for the other value?

Comment: @jpw just for other value. If discriminator = somethingelse then put Id of TableA in that column instead. That way, the Id's in the columns of TableB wont ever be the same (columns might be "StuffId" and "NotStuffId"). Its "NotStuffId" i want to fill now by checking for a different discriminator value in TableA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, reposting my comment as answer:

```
 INSERT TableB (StuffId) SELECT Id from TableA WHERE discriminator='Stuff'
```

should accomplish what you want as stated in the original post. Note that the new rows added in TableB will have null or a default value in the name field as it isn't specified in the query.

Edit: Depending on the design of TableB with regards to uniqueness and constraints this query might not give the correct result (for instance it might fail if there are already rows with the StuffId present in TableB if they're supposed to be unique, or it might add duplicate rows if they're not unique). Without a detailed description of the tables and how they are related it's difficult to provide a good answer.

Comment: Do you want to update the other column in TableB for existing rows or just insert new rows into the table?

Comment: just for other value. If discriminator = somethingelse then put Id of TableA in that column instead. That way, the Id's in the columns of TableB wont ever be the same (columns might be "StuffId" and "NotStuffId"). Its "NotStuffId" i want to fill now by checking for a different discriminator value in TableA

Comment: Well, tableB was basically created as a manytomany relationship in an MVC application and the 2 columns are foreign keys of TableA. But in data generation, the columns arent of correct type. I will be back in an hour or so to explain. Thank you so much for your help so far

Comment: @user1290653 Happy to help. Will check in later to see if you added anything.